# PHP CONSTANT not set but still prints something to screen?

Tags: php, constants

Isn't PHP suppose to show an error is you call a non-existent CONSTANT?  When I run the code below for a constant that is not defined, it shows on the screen "TEST" instead of any kind of error.  Could I have a setting wrong in my php.ini file or is this something new?  Im running PHP 5.3

```
<?php
echo TEST;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to show a notice which you may not have set as visible (E_NOTICE). On default, if the constant is not defined, it shows the literal value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default in php for an undefined constant to be silently replaced by a string representing its name. I think it can be disabled in php.ini, but it shouldn't be relied upon in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning or a notice, I'm not quite sure. The use of an undefined constant is not prohibited. However, `echo FOO BAR;` would indeed fail, because it's equivalent to `echo "FOO" "BAR";`.

Either your error_reporting setting does not show warnings or notices, or your display_errors setting is set to `false`.

You should not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have stated, referencing an undefined constant is a notice, not a fatal error (one that would cause PHP to stop running the script), and PHP will convert the constant name to a string and move on. Depending on your [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) setting, PHP might or might not print a message. You need to set it to at least [8 (E_NOTICE)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) before PHP prints the notice message. If what you want is to catch the undefined constant situation and handle it (e.g. have PHP print a message and exit), use the [defined](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function like this:

```
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
} else {
    // error handling here
}
```